# sort a dict type variable by value in python

Tags: python

I have a dict type variable like `{'key1':6,'key2':1,'key3':5,'key4':44}` my dictionary contains millions of key:val pair
I want to store it in txt file such that key corresponding to highest val comes first and so on in descending order
eg my txt file will look like

```
key4: 44
key1: 6
key3: 5
key2: 1
```

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value/4215710#4215710

Answer (score 4):

```
d = {'key1': 6, 'key2': 1, 'key3': 5, 'key4': 44}
for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
    print "%s: %s" % (k, d[k])
```

prints

```
key4: 44
key1: 6
key3: 5
key2: 1
```